# Replace error messages with zeros in a table

Tags: warning-messages

I'm working on a project of Nuclear physics and I'm passing results of a simulation program to mathematica via a txt file. I then read the values I need to read and plot them. The problem is that sometimes those values don't appear on the file, and then mathematica gets an "end of file" error instead of a value when I try to find them. Everything works fine with the plot, but if I want to show the results on a table it's all messed up and filled with errors.

TL;DR

How do I remove all the errors from a list like this:

```
{{40.,Internal`StringToDouble[StringSplit[EndOfFile][[6]]]},     
 {45.45,Internal`StringToDouble[StringSplit[EndOfFile][[6]]]},{50.91,49.5},
 {56.36,78.9},{61.82,70.9},{67.27,32.6},{72.73,9.4},{78.18,3.9},{83.64,1.1},
 {89.09,0.2},{94.55,0.1},{100.,Internal`StringToDouble[StringSplit[EndOfFile][[6]]]}}
```

replacing them with zeros?

I want to get something like this:

```
    {{40.,0},{45.45,0},{50.91,49.5},{56.36,78.9},{61.82,70.9},{67.27,32.6},
     {72.73,9.4},{78.18,3.9},{83.64,1.1},{89.09,0.2},{94.55,0.1},{100.,0}}
```

Thanks and sorry for the messy question.

Comment: (at) DoubleCat: It seems as if the value 0 is misinterpreted as an EOF marker. Try writing 0.0 instead of 0 in your text file.

Comment: That is what I want to get, I don't know how to do it

Comment: To try it, take a small txt file, replace an exact 0 by 0.0 e.g. by hand, and then pass this file to Mathematica. Do the error messages remain? If not, then you should adapt your text generation to include just this replacement. If yes, I don't know ...

Comment: `Replace[YourList, x_ /; Not@NumericQ@x :> 0, {2}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data /. Internal`StringToDouble[__] -> 0
```

> {{40., 0}, {45.45, 0}, {50.91, 49.5}, {56.36, 78.9}, {61.82, 70.9},
>   {67.27, 32.6}, {72.73, 9.4}, {78.18, 3.9}, {83.64, 1.1}, {89.09, 0.2},
>   {94.55, 0.1}, {100., 0}}

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me

Comment: My pleasure @ 2Cat